# How to return list of indices that contain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have an array of objects and would like to find each index that contains `first_name = 'Ryu'`.

```
let list = [{
  order:{
    contact: {
      first_name: 'Ryu'
    }
  }
},
{},{},{},...] // more order objects
```

I can check that a single index exists as follows:

```
let doesContactExist = list
  .map(i => i.order)
  .map(i => i.contact)
  .map(i => i.first_name).indexOf('Ryu')`
```

But how would I return a list of each indice that contains `Ryu`?

Comment: There's no need for 3 maps, just use `i.order.contact.first_name`

Comment: The last question is not clear. Are you wanting the index of `Ryu` in the `first_name`, or the index of the object whose `first_name` attribute contains `Ryu`?

Comment: @smac89 I'm looking to return all of the indices of the object whose `first_name` attribute contains `Ryu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to return either the index or `-1` depending on whether it matches the search string, then filter out all the `-1`.

```
let indexes = list.map(({order: {contact: {first_name}}}, i) => 
        first_name == 'Ryu' ? i : -1)
    .filter(i => i >= 0);
```

Comment: Why are you doing `.includes` instead of comparing for equality?

Comment: @Bergi code has been updated for direct comparison.

Comment: @Bergi Because the OP used `.indexOf()`, although he didn't use it correctly (you need to test if it's different from `-1`).

Comment: @Barmar He uses `indexOf` on the mapped list, not on a string

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for

```
const indices = list.map((obj, index) =>
    obj.order.contact.first_name == 'Ryu' ? index : -1
).filter(i =>
    i >=0
);
```

Comment: Hm... I'm doing something incorrect here. https://jsbin.com/wozunabupo/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Is `obj` short hand for `{order: {contact: {first_name}}}`?

Comment: @Matthew `obj` is the parameter that will refer to the elements of the `list`, yes. In your jsbin, you did wrap the arrow function expressions in blocks, where you would need to add a `return` keyword. Notice I didn't use any `{}`.

Comment: I see! I didn't realize that `{}` changed the `return` behavior. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` to transform your array into another array of indexes. The indexes are the one for which the object matched a predicate. (In this case the `a` property needs to contain the string `oo`):

```js
const foo =
  [ {a: 'foo'},
    {a: 'boo'},
    {a: 'bar'} ];
    
const idx = foo.reduce((acc, obj, i) =>
  obj.a.includes('oo') ? acc.concat(i) : acc, []);
  
console.log(idx);
```

Comment: I like the cleanliness of this code, but am having trouble understanding the reduce. I'll have to do some more reading...

Comment: Why are you doing `.includes` instead of comparing for equality?

Comment: @Bergi in the case of my answer I deliberately chose not to have the same data structure and predicate. In this case, as I have mentioned, the property we’re inspecting must only contains the string ‘oo’. Hopefully this sets OP in the right direction while allowing OP to learn along the way. (As opposed to serve a copy/paste answer. )

Answer (score 1):

No need to chain array functions and iterate multiple times; use `.reduce()` instead:

```js
let list = [
  {order:{contact: {first_name: 'Ryu'}}},    //0  <----
  {order:{contact: {first_name: 'Ken'}}},    //1
  {order:{contact: {first_name: 'Guile'}}},  //2
  {order:{contact: {first_name: 'Ryu'}}}     //3  <----
];

let result = list.reduce((output, {order:{contact:{first_name}}}, idx) => 
  first_name === 'Ryu'  //Is the first name Ryu?
    ? [...output, idx]  //Yes: Add the index to the result
    : output            //No:  Leave the result as-is
, []);

console.log(result);
```

If the first name only needs to *include* `"Ryu"` as opposed to an exact match, simply change `first_name === 'Ryu'` to `first_name.includes('Ryu')`.

Comment: Nice. I don't know why people would go for map & filter where you can just reduce. This seems like a no-brainer to me :) However if you look at the question, OP doesn't seem to be looking for an exact match though.

Comment: I think I use `map` and `reduce` more because I learned them first. I should do more reading on `reduce` to improve my problem solving methodology.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer!! +1 for Ken and Guile ;)

Comment: @Matthew Not a problem. `.map()` is fine, I just prefer `.reduce()` for more complex cases like these because it's more efficient to go through the array once as opposed to multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

`Array.prototype.filter()` [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is what you're looking for.

```
let doesContactExist = list.
  .map(i => i.order)
  .map(i => i.contact)
  .map(i => i.first_name).
  .map((name, i) => {name, i})
  .filter(({name}) => name === 'Ryu')
  .map({i} => i);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let list = [{
  order:{
    contact: {
      first_name: 'Ryu'
    }
  }
}]

const indices = list.reduce((accum, obj, index) => {
    if (obj.order.contact.first_name === 'Ryu') {
        accum.push(index);
    }
    return accum;
}, []);
```